# What is the relationship between $AA^T$ and $A^TA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

In the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \\ 5 & 6\end{pmatrix}$ then eigenvalues of $A^TA$ are eigenvalues of $AA^T$, and $AA^T$ has an eigenvalue of 0.  I've also experimented with other matrices enough to think this is generally true for any matrix $A$ of the same dimensions.  I can understand that the dimensions explain a nonempty nullspace and therefore eigenvalue of zero.

But for the other eigenvalues, I'd like to understand better why this is true, perhaps by giving a proof assuming that the proposition is true.

So if $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue with eigenvector $x$ for the matrix $AA^T$ then
$$ AA^Tx = \lambda x$$
The matrix $AA^T$ is a symmetric matrix and therefore $\lambda\ge 0$.  Also $AA^T$ is therefore orthogonally diagonalizable, so we could write
$$ AA^T=PDP^{-1} $$
where $P$ is an orthonormal matrix. Therefore $P^{-1}=P^T$.  So
$$PDP^Tx=\lambda x$$
so
$$D = \lambda P^TxP$$
I have no idea if this is going anywhere good, I'm just trying stuff out.  I can't think of any other direction to head in from here.

Comment: What you are looking for is this statement I think: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087064/non-zero-eigenvalues-of-aat-and-ata

Comment: [what's the relationship of A∗AT
and AT∗A](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/718363/55235)